# Why does the print function print to a file even when the file keyword argument is not specified?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I stumbled over code similar to the following, written by colleagues:

```
import fileinput

...

with fileinput.input(filename, inplace=1) as file:
    for line in file:
        print("// " + line)
```

This prepends all lines in the given file with `//` . It does not write anything to stdout.

Why does it do that even though `print` is called without the `file` keyword argument like this:

```
with open("bar.txt") as bar:
    print("foo", file=bar)
```

I've checked that there have been no assignments to `sys.stdout`.

Comment: "if the keyword argument ``inplace=True`` is passed to fileinput.input() [...] standard output is directed to the input file

Comment: Thank you! Somehow I skipped this when looking at the documentation for fileinput...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `inplace=1` argument redirects `sys.stdout` to the file:

https://docs.python.org/3/library/fileinput.html#fileinput.FileInput

> Optional in-place filtering: if the keyword argument `inplace=True` is passed to `fileinput.input()` or to the `FileInput` constructor, the file is moved to a backup file and standard output is directed to the input file (if a file of the same name as the backup file already exists, it will be replaced silently). This makes it possible to write a filter that rewrites its input file in place.

Since `print` writes to `sys.stdout` by default, it writes to the file in this case.

Comment: Thank you! Somehow I skipped this when looking at the documentation for fileinput...